# How can i make SmsManager API not show sent message and received message at same time

Tags: android

I am writing an app that sends the user of the app a text message when such user performs a certain action with the app. Now, i am using the SmsManager API to achieve this. Only problem is that sent message and received message is showing at the same time in messages. How do i fix this. Also, i want to change the name of the sender of the message to the app name.

```
public void sendSMSEntering() {
    String phone = "08187016641";
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, "Welcome to the ICAN 2019 conference" , null, null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void sendSMSExiting() {
    String phone = "08187016641";
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, "Goodbye. We hope you enjoyed the conference" , null, null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

My button from xml onClickListener

```
sendMeAMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickcount++;
                if (clickcount % 2 == 0) {
                    sendSMSEntering();
                } else {
                    sendSMSExiting();
                }
            }
        });
```

Screenshot

[image]

As can be observed in the image above, the message the app sent and the message received by me are both there. I only want the message received to be displayed in messages. Also you will observe that the sender of the message is my phone number (String phone = "08187016641"). 'phone' is used as both the recipients phone number and the sender of the message. Perhaps smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, "Goodbye. We hope you enjoyed the conference" , null, null); is not good enough to achieved this and needs to be changed to something else. I need suggestions

Answer (score 0):

After so much research I found out that the SMSManager API is whack. There are so many good SMS API's out there that you can integrate with your app. You can then use a GET or POST as appropriate to request SMS messages. These SMS API's give you the option of using a custom Sender name and other powerful options to customize incoming text messages. Some of these SMS API's include Nexmo SMS API, Ozeki SMS API and so many others. The good thing is, they have a comprehensive documentation. Infact, integrating these SMS API's into your app takes just a few lines of code.